# How to show hint using Application.ActivateHint on Delphi?

Tags: delphi, hint

I have the following code trying to show a hint:

```
procedure TMyGrid.OnGridMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
var
  aPoint: TPoint;
begin
  inherited;
  //Application.Hint := 'Hint Text';
  //Application.ShowHint := True;
  Grid.Hint := 'Hint Text';
  Grid.ShowHint := True;
  aPoint.X := X;
  aPoint.Y := Y;
  Application.ActivateHint(aPoint);
end;
```

But there is no hint appears. What's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`ActivateHint`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ActivateHint) wants your point in screen coordinates, not in client coordinates.

From doc:

> ActivateHint locates the control or menu item at the position specified by CursorPos, where **CursorPos represents a screen coordinates** in pixels. After locating the control, ActivateHint displays the control's Hint in a hint window.

So, you have to change your method like this:

```
procedure TMyGrid.OnGridMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
var
  aPoint: TPoint;
begin
  inherited;
  //Application.Hint := 'Hint Text';
  Grid.Hint := 'Hint Text';
  Grid.ShowHint := True;
  aPoint.X := X;
  aPoint.Y := Y;
  aPoint := ClientToScreen(aPoint);
  Application.ActivateHint(aPoint);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! But why hint didn't display outside window (with incorrect coordinates)?

Comment: It works OK in my case. Where do you expect it to appear? where it appears?

Comment: I think, correct code: `Grid.ClientToScreen`. It doesn't apear in my case - for example, X:200, Y:15.

Comment: Well, you know what is TMyGrid and what control the X,Y are relative to. I assumed that's a form, and the method is on the form, so a Self.ClientToScreen is correct, but you're the one who knows!

Answer (score 11):

Rather than trying to force `TApplication` to display a new Hint in your grid control's `OnMouseMove` event, the correct approach is to instead have your grid process the [`CM_HINTSHOW`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Controls.TCMHintShow) message to customize the current Hint whenever it is shown normally.

The `CM_HINTSHOW` message provides you with a pointer to a [`THintInfo`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.THintInfo) record in its `LPARAM` value.  `THintInfo` has a `CursorPos` member that tells you the current mouse position within the control's client area, and a `CursorRect` member that allows you to define a rectangle within the control's client area that the current hint should be valid for (`THintInfo` has other members for customizing the hint further, suh as text, color, window class, show/hide timeouts, etc).  When the mouse moves outside of that rectangle but is still within the control's client area, the `CM_HINTSHOW` message is generated again to obtain new information to update the current Hint with.

If you need to update the hint on every mouse move, you can define a custom `CursorRect` that only contains the current `CursorPos`, for example:

```
type
  TMyGrid = class(...)
  private
    procedure CMHintShow(var Message: TCMHintShow); message CM_HINTSHOW;
  end;

procedure TMyGrid.CMHintShow(var Message: TCMHintShow);
begin
  with Message.HintInfo^ do
  begin
    HintStr := Format('Hint Text (%d,%d)', [CursorPos.X, CursorPos.Y]);
    CursorRect := Rect(CursorPos.X, CursorPos.Y, CursorPos.X, CursorPos.Y);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed too. I was worrying about whether just to change the hint text in an OnMouseMove and/or call Application.CancelHint first, and what affect this would have on the timeout. Now I know that's the wrong approach.

Comment: By the way, this also works with `Application.OnShowHint` for those times when you don't want to/can't subclass the control.

Comment: @IanGoldby: You can always subclass a control, even if you have to resort to using its `WindowProc` property to do so. But yes, what you say is true. The THintInfo is first sent to the component via `CM_HINTSHOW`. If the component does not reject it (by returning a non-zero value) then the `THintInfo` is sent to the `TApplication.OnShowHint` event handler, if assigned. If the event handler does not reject it (by setting the `CanShow` parameter to false, or clearing the `THintInfo.HintStr` field), then the `THintInfo` is used to activate/update the hint window.